# Why all buttons receive the same state at once in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-style

I have the following style for buttons:

```xml
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Roboto" />
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{StaticResource ButtonMinHeight}" />
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{StaticResource ButtonMinWidth}" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{StaticResource ButtonPadding}" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border x:Name="bMain" 
                            CornerRadius="{StaticResource ButtonCornerRadius}" 
                            BorderThickness="{StaticResource ButtonBorderThickness}" 
                            BorderBrush="Transparent" 
                            Background="{StaticResource ButtonBackgroundBrush}"
                            TextBlock.Foreground="{StaticResource ButtonForegroundBrush}">
                        <ContentPresenter Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="bMain" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                            <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ButtonHoverBackgroundColor}" />
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="bMain" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                            <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ButtonDownBackgroundColor}" />
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="bMain" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                                            <DiscreteColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource ButtonDisabledForegroundColor}" />
                                        </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    </Border>

                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsDefault" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="bMain" Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ButtonBorderBrush}" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Also, I have two buttons:

```xml
<Button Grid.Column="1" Command="{Binding LogCommand}" Content="{x:Static r:Strings.Main_Button_Log}" Margin="0,0,24,0"/>
<Button Grid.Column="2" Command="{Binding CloseCommand}" Content="{x:Static r:Strings.Main_Button_Close}" />
```

The problem is that they both seem to receive the same state at the same time.

Normal:

[image: Normal state]

Hover (on one of them):

[image]

If the images are not distinct enough, in the second one both buttons became highlighted instead of only one. The case is the same for pressing.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Could you please share more xaml and resources?

Comment: @user2250152, Try putting this code in Window's resources (or in separate resource dictionary and then use MergedResources).
When placed like in app.xaml, it indeed started working again. I'm curious though, why it didn't work in the first place.